# p-datatable - Change of width of column

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG dataTable. I would like to change the width of a column.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="client" sortField="order">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name">
        <template let-col let-client="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <span>{{client[col.field]}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="id" styleClass="id-width">
        <template let-col let-client="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <button pButton type="button" icon="fa fa-pencil" iconPos="left" (click)="edit(client[col.field])"></button>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

In the `id` column I put `styleClass="id-width"` and in css file I put the following:

```
.id-width {
    width: 49px;
}
```

However, according to the image below, the width remains unchanged.
The two columns remain the same size.

[image]

Comment: PrimeNG != PrimeFaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Of:
    `<p-column field="id" styleClass="id-width">`

To:
    `<p-column field="id" [style]="{'width':'49px'}">`